# How to pass arguments to a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, syntax-error, python-multithreading

I have **`test()`** as shown below:

```py
def test(arg1, arg2=None, arg3=None):
```

Now, I tries to create a thread using **`test()`**, and giving it only **`arg1`** and **`arg2`** but not arg3 as shown below:

```py
threading.Thread(target=test, args=(arg1, arg2=arg2)).start()
```

But, I got a syntax error. How can I solve the error so that I can pass an argument to the thread as arg2?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use the [kwargs parameter](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

```py
threading.Thread(target=test, args=(arg1,), kwargs={'arg2':arg2}).start()
```

Answer (score 6):

you can also use lambda to pass args

```py
threading.Thread(target=lambda: test(arg1, arg2=arg2, arg3=arg3)).start()
```